# Redirect using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I just switched servers and my site is on a new ip address. I guess the previous owner of this ip address still has his domain pointing to my ip. So when you go to his domain name my site shows up. He can't make changes or anything like that, but it's messing with my search engine rankings. I was wondering if I can us htaccess to redirect his domain to mine so something like this

if(his domain){
redirect to my site
}

of course you can't use if statements like that in .htacess but you get my drift.

Thanks

Comment: What you need is modrewrite. this question has been asked and answered many times before

Comment: Yes it has, but my question wasn't the same as the 1000's of mod rewrite questions I found on here and on google. :)

Answer (score 0):

Question is not fully clear. Based on my understanding as it is not mod_rewrite question, here my answer:
 Public ip is unique and hope you mixed up with domain name and ip in question. If your domain pointed to your server ip, there should not be any problem. However if both domains hosted on same server(ip), then you could use virtualhost config to point to correct site similar to ReverseProxy ProxyPass.

If search engines currently indexed your site pages with old ip address, then no choice there for you. You may trigger search engines to re-index.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Host} ^www\.his_domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* http://www.yoursite.com [R=301]
```